# Python Match List with appropriate list

Tags: python, pandas

Need to match the lists with appropriate value, i was able to match with two lists, but here involved three lists.

```
# **Main List**
main_list = ['munnar', 'ooty', 'coonoor', 'nilgri', 'wayanad', 'coorg', 'chera', 'hima']

# **List1**
List1 = ['ooty', 'coonoor', 'chera']

# **List2**
List2 = ['hill', 'hill', 'hill']

# **List3**
List3 = ['nilgri', 'hima']

# **List4**
List4 = ['mount', 'mount']
```

`List1` belong to `List2` same `List3` belong to `List4`,

I can match `List1` with `List2` and `List3` with `List4` using list comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame(
    list(zip(List1, List2)),
    columns=('Area', 'Content')
)

Area    Content
ooty    hill
coonoor hill
chera   hill
```

And

```
pd.DataFrame(
    list(zip(List3, List4)),
    columns=('Area', 'Content')
)


Area    Content
nilgri  mount
hima    mount
```

`List1` and `List3` is available in Main List, now have to match `List2` and
`List4` in Main List. if its not matching then it need to have `NA`
Expecting below output using pandas.

```
Area    Content
munnar  NA
ooty    hill
coonoor hill
nilgri  mount
wayanad NA
coorg   NA
chera   hill
hima    mount
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Can you share the code of what you have done so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do `reindex` after `concat` the df1 and df2

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).set_index('Area').reindex(mainlist).reset_index()
df
Out[91]: 
      Area Content
0   munnar     NaN
1     ooty    hill
2  coonoor    hill
3   nilgri   mount
4  wayanad     NaN
5    coorg     NaN
6    chera    hill
7     hima   mount
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time and solution you have did.  can we have df1 and df2 in seperate column. i have scenario mainlist will sometime have value in both df1/df2. if both are in sepearte column it will be great

Comment: @selvamsamymuthu`pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)` is this what you need ?

Comment: `Area text1 text2
munnar NA 
ooty hill mount
coonoor hill 
nilgri  mount
wayanad NA 
coorg NA 
chera hill 
hima  mount`

Comment: @selvamsamymuthu i will recommend open an new question about it

Answer (score 3):

```
main_list = ['munnar', 'ooty', 'coonoor', 'nilgri', 'wayanad', 'coorg', 'chera', 'hima']

list1 = ['ooty', 'coonoor', 'chera']
list2 = ['hill', 'hill', 'hill']
list3 = ['nilgri', 'hima']
list4 = ['mount', 'mount']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Area=main_list))

df.assign(Content=df.Area.map(dict([*zip(list1, list2), *zip(list3, list4)])))


      Area Content
0   munnar     NaN
1     ooty    hill
2  coonoor    hill
3   nilgri   mount
4  wayanad     NaN
5    coorg     NaN
6    chera    hill
7     hima   mount

​
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time and solution you have given. I have one more scenario, some of data will be available in both tables. is it possible to put the output in three different columns as Main list, hill, mount. for ex. ooty will be available in both table. so if there are 3 table, it will show exact answer. please help. thanks